# Elevating user to root with Ansible

Tags: linux, automation, root, ansible

How to elevate Ansible to root for running playbooks? The thing is that the server I want to provision has root access disabled and the only user that has login access has absolutely no permissions to do anything except elavating to other users.

So when I login to server manually I would do something like this - `ssh lgus11@vdom7.intrn` and then if I need to install something I would either do `sudo - myuser` or in some rare occasions `sudo -` and then enter the respective users password.

Unfortunately if I run my Ansible playbook I can't seem to be able to elevate the user to root.

I have a line like this in my `/etc/ansible/hosts` file:

```
[vault_server]
vdom7.intrn ansible_become=true ansible_become_user="root" ansible_become_password="<root_user_password>"
```

And the result I get from running the playbook is as follows:

```
PLAY [vault_server] ********************************************************* 

GATHERING FACTS *************************************************************** 
fatal: [vdom7.intrn] => Incorrect become password

PLAY RECAP ******************************************************************** 
           to retry, use: --limit @/home/user/main.retry

vdom7.intrn                : ok=0    changed=0    unreachable=1    failed=0
```

I know `ansible_become_password` does have some effect because previously I used to get `Missing become password` for an error but at the same time I know that the password I provide is correct for the user because when I use it manually it works like a charm and so I'm not really aware what am I doing wrong and how should I change playbook's run user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`become` defaults to using `sudo` ([see `become_method`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/become.html)). So you need to use the *user's* password as you would provide to sudo, not the root password.

Or you can change the `become_method`, e.g. to `su`.

Comment: The problem is that the user I have access to is not in sudoers and so it has no way to actually use sudo. Is there some way to do `su -` rather than use `sudo`?

Comment: Did you click the link? Use `become_method: su`.

Comment: Awesome, exactly what I needed. Thanks. I guess I should've read the manual more thoroughly.